# keep diskpart command line open after command execution

Tags: windows, vbscript, scripting

I'm working in a script that takes screenshots of the terminal after execution a list of commands, one of those commands is `list disk` in "diskpart command line" this is the what I've coded:

```
Set args = WScript.Arguments
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

Dim comando
comando = "list disk"

objShell.CurrentDirectory = "C:"
objShell.Run ("diskpart command line" & comando)
WScript.Sleep(5000)
```

Everything is working, but after the command is executed, the terminal disappear and the screenshot cannot be taken. How can I pause the terminal execution?

I've also tried with this line:

```
objShell.Run ("cmd /k diskpart " & comando)
```

but `/k` is not making any difference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parameter `/k` keeps the CMD instance running. It does not affect the `diskpart` command. If you want to keep an interactive `diskpart` prompt after running a command just run `diskpart` a second time (use `&` for daisy-chaining the commands). Also, `diskpart` doesn't accept commands as parameters. You must either write them to a script and call that via `diskpart /s SCRIPT` or pipe the command into `diskpart`.

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
cmd = "list disk"
sh.Run "cmd /k ""echo " & cmd & " | diskpart & diskpart"""
```

Replace `/k` with `/c` if you want the CMD window to close automatically when you exit from `diskpart`.